# How can I get a specific element on a json-like string in javascript?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I'm writing a node.js/angular app and in my backend code I have:

```
res.json(body);
```

then in my front end I have:

```
$scope.countryName = function() {
    $http.get('/get/some/numbers').success(function (data) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
    })
}
```

When I put `localhost:3000/get/some/numbers` in the browser, I see: `2;12;1234;43253242643`. How can I get e.g. a 3rd value (`1234`) and assign it to a variable? Btw, do I need to use a `JSON.stringify` in the frontend since I'm using `res.json(body)` in the backend?

Comment: `2;12;1234;43253242643` is not valid JSON.

Comment: Ok, sorry for that, I'm also confused. Actually when I do a res.json(body) in my backend that's the string that I'm receiving and all I want is to get a third value from it

Comment: How does your `body` look like? It seems to me `body` and `data` are simple strings.

Answer (score 1):

That isn't valid JSON but assuming it is a simple string, if you want the nth segment of numbers you would do:

```
var value = data;
var segment = value.split(';')[n]
```

where `n` is the numbered segment you want. so `value.split(';')[2]` would result in `1234`.

[Here is a working example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vLpMKO)

Comment: `2;12;1234;43253242643` isn't valid JSON but `"2;12;1234;43253242643"` is.

Comment: What exactly is the purpose of `JSON.stringify` here? What do you think what type `data` is if the value is `2;12;1234;43253242643` ?

Comment: @FelixKling I am just taking his example. As I mentioned, his response is not valid JSON but assuming it is a string such as the one he posted this would be the way to do what he wants

Comment: @Paulpro: Nope. Any value that be expressed in JSON is valid JSON. `42`, `"foo"`, `null`, `{"foo": 42}`, `[1,2,3]`, `true`, `false`.

Comment: @Pabs123: If it's a string, then why do you do `JSON.stringify`?

Comment: Fair, it is redundant, I will remove it

Comment: It's not just redundant, it's wrong. Compare the output of `"foo bar".split(' ')[0]` with `JSON.stringify("foo bar").split(' ')[0]`.

Comment: @Paulpro: That used to be the case but it isn't anymore. See https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7159 (which obsoletes 4627).

Comment: @FelixKling Oh I hadn't seen that RFC. That's interesting, thanks. I guess it would have to be an old parser then ;)